# How to pass a property to html helper method

Tags: vb.net, html-helper

I have an html helper class for my webforms projects. so far it can return strings to create labels and readonly fields.

```
Public Shared Function DisplayFor(value As String, Optional attributes As String = "") As String
    Return [String].Format("<span class='uneditable-input {0}'>{1}</span>", GetSStyle(attributes), value)
End Function
```

Now I want to create some overloads that can accept passing the entity property so it can internally check the datatype (from attributes) and display the content formatted, for example. Just as MVC does.

The only problem it's that I don't know how to pass a class property as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a property as an `Expression(Of Func(Of MyModel, String))` and by that receive an expression in the method that you can analyze and evaluate:

```
Public Shared Function DisplayFor(Of TModel, TValue)(model As TModel, expr As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TValue))) As String
    ' Retrieve the value dynamically
    Dim compExpr = expr.Compile()
    Dim value = compExpr.DynamicInvoke(model)
    Dim retVal As String
    If value Is Nothing Then
        retVal = String.Empty
    Else
        retVal = value.ToString()
    End If
    ' Analyze expression body
    Dim memberAccExpr = DirectCast(expr.Body, 
                          System.Linq.Expressions.MemberAccessExpression)
    Dim attr = memberAccExpr.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyDisplayAttribute), false).Cast(Of MyDisplayAttribute)().FirstOrDefault();
    Return retVal
End Function
```

Call the method like this:

```
DisplayFor(myModelVar, Function(m) m.MyProperty)
```

I hope this sample gives you a rough outline on how to handle this. Please note that especially the analysis of the expression body is simplified. In real world code there would be various checks to make sure that the expression matches your expectations.

Comment: I've tried to implement the signature you described, and I get some errors. If I call at codebehind: "Argument not specified for parameter 'expr' of 'public func...'" And "Parameter 'm' hides property 'MyForm.m as MytableRow' 
If I include it at the markup: "Cannot convert type 'lambda expression' to parameter type 'String'.
Please remember that I'm using this function in webforms, and no Html object is there or MVC parsing.

Comment: @Sergio: sorry, everything looked "so MVC" that I went in the wrong direction. I've updated my answer to show a way without MVC helper.

Comment: After your edit, the code works well. However, I'm forced to do the invocation like this: <%= DisplayFor(myModelVar, Function(m As myModelVarClass) m.MyProperty)%> And it's a little annoying. Is there any way of eliminating the need to define the type of m, or having to pass MyRow and only get the value from the field? Anyway, thank you. That little piece of code will save me to write a lot!

Comment: @Sergio: good to know that it helped. The types of the generic arguments can sometimes not be inferred automatically. I don't know a workaround other than putting the "As MyModelVarClass" there.